# Recursive function to traverse grid goes crazy

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

When the user clicks on one of the blocks in the table ( see screenshot ) I want to find all neighbouring blocks with the same color. I am trying to do this recursively, but if I try it with more than three blocks it sometimes goes crazy and calls itself over and over until the program crashes.

As far as I can see, the objects are added to the array, but somehow my tests fails and the same object is added over and over and over.

Any insight on what the problem might be and how to solve it would be much appriciated!

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXyHN.png)

This is the function that is called when the user clicks on a block:

```
var $matchArray;
$('.block').click(function () {

    $matchArray = [$(this)];

    var $colorClass;

    if ($(this).hasClass('red')) {
        $colorClass = 'red';
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('green')) {
        $colorClass = 'green';
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('blue')) {
        $colorClass = 'blue';
    } else {
        $colorClass = 'error';
    }

    findAllSameColorNeighbours($(this), $colorClass);

});
```

And this is the recursive method:

```
findAllSameColorNeighbours = function ($this, $colorClass) {

    $this.css('border-style', 'solid');

    //LEFT
    var $leftBlock = isLeftBlockSameColor($this, $colorClass);
    if ($leftBlock != null) {
        if (!(arrayContains($matchArray, $leftBlock))) {
            $matchArray.push($leftBlock);
            findAllSameColorNeighbours($leftBlock, $colorClass);
        }
    }

    //ABOVE
        //same as for LEFT
    //RIGHT
        //same as for LEFT
    //BELOW
        //same as for LEFT
}
```

This is how I find the neighboring cells, as far as I can see these work just fine. I have one for each direction:

```
isLeftBlockSameColor = function ($block, $color) {
    var $this = $block;
    var $tr = $this.parent().parent();
    var col = $tr.children().index($this.parent().prev());
    var $leftBlock = $this.parent().siblings().eq(col).children();
    var $blockClassMatch = $leftBlock.hasClass($color);

    if ($blockClassMatch) {
        return $leftBlock;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
};
```

Here are some help methods to find out if the object is already in the array or not. I use the index of the row and cell to create a sort of latitude and longditude thing.

```
arrayContains = function ($array, $object) {

    for (i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
        if (compareIndex($array[i], $object)) {
            say('true');
            return true;
        }
    };
    return false;
};

compareIndex = function ($obj1, $obj2) {

    if ((getRowIndex($obj1)) === (getRowIndex($obj2)) {
        if ((getCellIndex($obj1)) === (getCellIndex($obj2)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }

};

getCellIndex = function ($this) {
    var $tr = $this.parent().parent();
    var index = $tr.children().index($this.parent());
    return index;
};

getRowIndex = function ($this) {
    var $tr = $this.parent().parent();
    var index = $tr.index();
    return index;
};
```

Comment: You should provide a code snippet or jsFiddle replicating your issue

Comment: @PeCeSe, I would suggest replacing the recursive logic with jQuery's find. Ofcourse you cannot directly do that. Try to set colors by classes and use `find` to find the classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in the `arrayContains` function. The loop will iterates only once, because Array.length is equals to 1(As I tested with chrome browser, but I don't know why). You should use `$array.length` instead.

```
arrayContains = function ($array, $object) {
        //for (i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
        for (i = 0; i < $array.length; i++) {
            if (compareIndex($array[i], $object)) {
                say('true');
                return true;
            }
        };
        return false;
    };
```

Comment: OMG!!! Dat typo!! Thank you so much, I could have kept staring at this the whole night without finding it!!